# Add a constructor to an existing structure

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to add a constructor to the Rectangle `Structure`?

Is this even possible without inheriting from the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add an external constructor to a structure.

The thing you can do is to declare somewhere a static class with the function you need that returns a rectangle.

```
Public Class Utilities

    Public Shared Function GetMySpecialRectangle(ByVal x As Integer) As Rectangle
        Return New Rectangle(x, 0, 100, 100)
    End Function

End Class
```

And to use it...

```
Dim r As Rectangle = Utilities.GetMySpecialRectangle(19)
```

In some specific circumstance you can also use Extension methods.
If you never heard about that, there is an example.

```
Module MyExtensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ToMySpecialRectangle(ByVal x As Integer) As Rectangle
        Return New Rectangle(x, 0, 100, 100)
    End Function

End Module
```

And to use it...

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim rect As Rectangle = x.ToMySpecialRectangle()
```

This actually adds an "extension" method to class Integer, an extension method mimics a class method, but is a just a static module method called with a different syntax.

It just means that each time you do `integerValue.ToMySpecialRectangle()` you are calling the module function `ToMySpecialRectangle(integerValue)` instead, just *syntactic sugar*.

There is however nothing like that about constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong Rectangle is NotInheritable Class Rectangle which inherits Shape and you can not inherit **NotInheritable**

Comment: It depends, I guess he is talking about windows form, and in windows form, rectangle is a simple structure.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about it :)